Retrieving $Matches from -match in Switch condition
I have a switch statement that is rather long (over 120 codes) and is a simple string match to where a certain string/code will cause a certain set of commands to execute (so no need for regex).  But, as I was thinking about it, it occurred to me that I would like to pass usernames through same switch to do the same task per each user, using their username.
I attempted to do this by placing a -match inside the condition with a named capturing group regex to grab the username, but it failed:
$code1 = 'Descriptive text describing code 1'
$code2 = 'Descriptive text describing code 2'
$userName1 = 'user_UserName1'
$userName2 = 'user_UserName2'
$Codes = $code1, $code2, $userName1, $userName2
switch ($Codes) {
   $code1 {
      Write-Host 'Do work required by code1'
      continue
   }
   $code2 {
      Write-Host 'Do work required by code2'
      continue
   }
   {$_ -match '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$'} {
      Write-Host ('Processing user: {0}' -f $Matches.UserName)
      continue
   }
   default {'Other'}
}

Failed results:
Do work required by code1
Do work required by code2
Processing user:
Processing user:

Where I expected this:
Do work required by code1
Do work required by code2
Processing user: UserName1
Processing user: UserName2

And while the following does work, as you can see, I'm having to execute the -match twice:
$Codes = 'user_UserName1', 'user_UserName2'
switch ($Codes) {
   {$_ -match '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$'} {
      if($_ -match '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$') {
         Write-Host ('Processing user: {0}' -f $Matches.UserName)
      }
      continue
   }
   default {'Other'}
}

I'm guessing the condition is a script block executed in its own scope and $Matches isn't available outside that scope.  I can't return $userName from within the script block since I'm sure the that is how the $true/$false value is received by switch.
Is there a simple method to avoid matching once for switch and then again to make $Matches available?
Final Code Based on Santiago's answer and comments:
Using information from here, created an extension class for extending the string type to include reEscape method.  This allows me to simply add .reEscape() to a string to create the regex escaped version of the string.  For example, 'This is a test.'.reEscape() creates "This\ is\ a\ test\.":
class MyExtensions {
   static [string]reEscape([PSObject]$source) {
      return [regex]::Escape($source)
   }
}
Update-TypeData -TypeName 'System.String' -MemberName 'reEscape' -MemberType CodeMethod -Value ([MyExtensions].GetMethod('reEscape')) -Force

For testing, added characters that regex will need escaped ((, ), and .) to $code1 and $code2:
$code1 = 'Descriptive text (with special characters) describing code 1.'
$code2 = 'Descriptive text (with special characters) describing code 2.'
$userName1 = 'user_UserName1'
$userName2 = 'user_UserName2'
$Codes = $code1, $code2, $userName1, $userName2

Upgraded the switch statement to include the -regex switch, and added .reEscape() to $code1 and $code2:
switch -Regex ($Codes) {
   $code1.reEscape() {
      Write-Host 'Do work required by code1'
      continue
   }
   $code2.reEscape() {
      Write-Host 'Do work required by code2'
      continue
   }
   '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$' {
      Write-Host ('Processing user: {0}' -f $Matches.UserName)
      continue
   }
   default { 'Other' }
}

In conclusion, I'm not excited by the idea of having to add .reEscape() to the end of strings to make them safe for regex, but it's an acceptable solution.


I'm guessing the condition is a script block executed in its own scope and $Matches isn't available outside that scope.

That's correct, simply proven by:
& { $null = 'user_UserName1' -match '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$' }; $Matches

# `$Matches` isn't populated in the caller scope


Is there a simple method to avoid matching once for switch and then again to make $Matches available?

switch has a -Regex parameter and the $Matches variable is populated when using it.
# NOTE: $var = [regex]::Escape('....')
#       can be used on variable assignment for literal match on switch conditions

$code1 = 'Descriptive text describing code 1'
$code2 = 'Descriptive text describing code 2'
$userName1 = 'user_UserName1'
$userName2 = 'user_UserName2'
$Codes = $code1, $code2, $userName1, $userName2

switch -Regex ($Codes) {
    $code1 {
        Write-Host 'Do work required by code1'
        continue
    }
    $code2 {
        Write-Host 'Do work required by code2'
        continue
    }
    '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$' {
        Write-Host ('Processing user: {0}' -f $Matches.UserName)
        continue
    }
    default {
        'Other'
    }
}


Thank you, but in an attempt at making a minimal example, I left little bit off the design, so I updated the question.  I guess I could change the $codeN strings to a regex format, but I was kind of wanting to avoid that.  See the top part of the code for exactly what I'm doing.

@Darin as long as $codeN don't have regex special characters I don't see a need for changing anything. the code still works fine as is.

From this, it looks like this .^$*+?()[{\| should be avoided, is this correct?  I could check $Codes for these characters prior to the switch and throw an error

You can use [regex]::Escape on variable assignments when needed. It isn't expensive at all and will take care of possible regex characters in your strings @Darin

Thank you!  I didn't know [regex]::Escape was an option.  I like that solution, I could run a quick "regex upgrade" to each code in codes prior to the switch statement.

Thanks for updating. As for $Matches not getting populated directly in the caller's scope: as far as I know, this only happens if the -match operator's LHS is array-valued (an object that PowerShell considers enumerable in a pipeline context).

Added a final code section based on your help. Thank you!  Only solution I could come up with was to escape everything and then use unescape on the codes just before the switch statement.

Here's another way using the $script: (or $global:) scope and a $myMatches variable.  I guess you could just say "$global:matches = $matches", or "Set-Variable Matches $Matches -scope 1".
$code1 = 'Descriptive text describing code 1'
$code2 = 'Descriptive text describing code 2'
$userName1 = 'user_UserName1'
$userName2 = 'user_UserName2'
$Codes = $code1, $code2, $userName1, $userName2

switch ($Codes) {
   $code1 {
      Write-Host 'Do work required by code1'
      continue
   }
   $code2 {
      Write-Host 'Do work required by code2'
      continue
   }
   {$_ -match '^user_(?<UserName>.*)$'; $script:myMatches = $Matches} {
      Write-Host ('Processing user: {0}' -f $myMatches.UserName)
      continue
   }
   default {'Other'}
}

Do work required by code1
Do work required by code2
Processing user: UserName1
Processing user: UserName2

